# Why is my InnoDB table size so much larger than the data?

Tags: innodb, disk-space, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL table (version 8.0.13). One table is unreasonably large and doesn't correspond to the current data. I rebuilt the table by running `ALTER TABLE users FORCE` and `OPTIMIZE TABLE users`, but they did not help. The two culprits I imagine are: variable length columns causing extra storage to be allocated, or deleted rows causing fragmentation. (The column types are listed at the end.)

When I examine the data with `LENGTH(col)`, I don't see anything amiss. From `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, I see:

```
`users`:
Engine: InnoDB
Avg_row_length: 212077938
Data_length: 25237274624
Data_free: 4194304
Index_length: 32768
Rows: 119
```

I know this is wrong because I copied the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_copy` LIKE `users`;
INSERT INTO `users_copy` SELECT * FROM `users`;
```

When I examine the new table, I see the following statistics (the differing row count is because the first table is constantly being modified):

```
`users_copy`:
Engine: InnoDB
Avg_row_length: 132270
Data_length: 16269312
Data_free: 3145728
Index_length: 32768
Rows: 123
```

So why is the data length so much longer in the original table, and can I fix the table online? If the answer isn't apparent, how can I debug it? Note that the DB is running on AWS so I don't think I have access to the filesystem.

Note: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` gives:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_copy` (
  `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `data1` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data2` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data3` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data4` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data5` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data6` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data7` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data8` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data9` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data10` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data11` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data12` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`,`token`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=735580 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

UPDATE: Almost a day after I ran the `OPTIMIZE` and `ALTER` commands, the size was reduced to something more reasonable (but still far larger than it should have been). I would love to know how to trigger this change predictably.

Comment: Give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users_copy\G` - I'll bet that the table has indexes that are bloating it. This may or may not be a problem depending on your requirements - so it may (or may not) require "fixing"! Your JSON columns might have high variability in their size - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711346/470530).